# implicit type conversion - mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, type-conversion

looking for some assistance regarding type conversion in C sharp please. I am creating an app using MVC and Entity Framework core. Right now I am implementing identities but I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'GymBuddy.Data.Entities.RepoUser' to 'System.Threading.Task.Task' when I am creating an asynchronous method. 
I have read a few articles about type conversion but I am still not clear about this issue. Not necessarily looking for the answer but maybe some directions on how to explore further this problem. Thanks in advance.

First I have created the RepoUser class with a couple of simple properties.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
namespace GymBuddy.Data.Entities
{
public class RepoUser : IdentityUser
    {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Second I have created a class which will in the future seed the database but will also check if a user exists.

```
using GymBuddy.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GymBuddy.Data
{
public class GymBuddySeeder
{   
    private readonly UserManager<RepoUser> _userManager;
    public GymBuddySeeder(UserManager<RepoUser> userManager)
    {   
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public async Task Seed()
    {
        var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("john.smith@hotmail.com");
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new RepoUser()
```

As soon as I type "RepoUser" (the first line in here basically) the error message described above pops up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming FindByEmailAsync is actually an async method, it likely returns a Task. This means that user is a Task not a RepoUser. So when you try to set user (a Task) to new RepoUser you are getting a type mismatch for which there is no implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("john.smith@hotmail.com");
```

to

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("john.smith@hotmail.com");
```

the `Async` at the end of `FindByEmailAsync` indicates that it probably returns a `Task<RepoUser>`. Don't take my word for it, of course, see what it returns.

Calling the method returns the task. Awaiting the asynchronous value returns the value returned with the task.

Comment: The line he has a problem with will still be a problem. He still won't be able to set user = new RepoUser().

Comment: It won't be a problem *if* `RepoUser` is assignable to whatever type is returned by `FindByEmailAsync`.

Comment: @Kevin `FindByEmailAsync` should return the identity user, which RepoUser probably is. FindByEmailAsync is part of the generic `UserManager<TUser>` - and short of some custom implementation that should be it.

Comment: Thank you guys, both answers make perfect sense and it worked!